# Restrict user to create functions only in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

It is possible to restrict the privileges of a role to create functions and procedures only AND avoiding to create tables within its own schema?
The CREATE privilege seems not so granulated as Oracle does. I can create any object with the CREATE privilege.

Comment: You need to read role based access - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/user-manag.html

Comment: i assume he already did @jimmy8ball as he is mentoned *"The CREATE privilege seems not so granulated as Oracle does."* and he is right you don't have `CREATE FUNCTION/PROCEDURE` privilege in PostgreSQL. so making a role also will not matter..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - dont assume anything

Comment: *" dont assume anything "* call it a educated "geuss" when reading the statement *"The CREATE privilege seems not so granulated as Oracle does. I can create any object with the CREATE privilege."* from the question @jimmy8ball

Comment: .. maybe some extension exists to achieve this? Or any tricky idea?

Comment: You could prevent all DDL except CREATE FUNCTION in an event trigger.